# vba to color font in adjacent columns

Tags: excel, vba

In this particular spreadsheet in column E from cell E6 onwards I have the values 0 or 1, having converted a number to binary. In the adjacent cells I have values i.e. in cells F6 and G6. If the value is 0 in column E I want the font in columns F and G to be grey color RGB(192,192,192), if the value is 1 in column E then I want the font to be made bold in columns F and G. 
I need to do this programmatically as I am trying to achieve this on a change event.

Comment: Please add an example spreadsheet of what you want to achieve. It will be much helpful.

Comment: welcome to SO. Have you tried to code this already? Even used the "record macro" feature? You will find you get a much more positive response from the community here if you show us what you've already done and tried, and where you got stuck and need help. You will also find the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) useful.

Comment: Sorry new to this forum, please advise on how to upload file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the coloring to happen anytime something is changed on the sheet, we need to look at the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Go to the VB Editor by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or, under the Developer tab, select Visual Basic.

In the editor, right click the worksheet that you want this formatting to occur on and then select View Code.

Paste the collowing code in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim c As Range

        'Get the last used row in column E
        lRow = Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        'Go through column E and check values
        For Each c In Range("E1:E" & lRow)
                If c.Value = 0 Then
                        'Offsets to column F, G and colors font
                        'if the value in column E is 0
                        c.Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
                        c.Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
                End If
        Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, appreciated that coding works fine. However, on the next event change the cells that were greyed out remain grey. I think I have the general idea to adjust the coding from here.

Comment: No problem!  This at least gives you a good start, if you have difficulty figuring out how to accomplish your task ask another question and we'll help!